# Multi or n-armed bandit reinforcement learning in R

Tags: r, ai, machine-learning

I am learning about reinforcement learning and came across the first and simplest form of reinforcement learning system called multi-armed reinforcement learning (also called as n-armed bandit). I have read Sutton's book and an [outlace.com](http://outlace.com/Reinforcement-Learning-Part-1/) tutorial regarding this learning. Outlace.com has written a nice Python implementation of this learning which I rewrote as an R program.

```
#multi/n-armed bandit algorithm with greedy search
#original code http://outlace.com/Reinforcement-Learning-Part-1/

iter=500
n=10
arms=runif(n)
eps=0.1
av=rep.int(1,n)
counts=rep.int(0,n)

#reward function
reward<-function(prob){
  reward=0
  for (i in 1:100){
    if(runif(1)<prob){
      reward=reward+1
    }
    return(reward)
  }
}

bestArm<-function(a){
  return(max(a))
}

runMean=NULL
for (i in 1:iter){
  if(runif(1) > eps){    
    # exploitation!(use best arm)
    choice=bestArm(av)
    counts[choice]=counts[choice]+1
    k = counts[choice]
    #reward for n arms
    rwd =  reward(arms[choice])    
    old_avg = av[choice]
    new_avg = old_avg + (1/k)*(rwd - old_avg) #update running avg
    av[choice] = new_avg

  }else{
    # exploration!(test all arm)
    # choose a random lever 10% of the time.  

    #randomly chose an arm
    choice=sample(arms,1)    
    counts[choice]=counts[choice]+1
    old_avg = av[choice]
    new_avg = old_avg + (1/k)*(rwd - old_avg) #update running avg
    av[choice] = new_avg
  }
  runMean[i]=mean(av)  
}
plot(runMean)
```

I don't know whether the output is correct because I don't understand some parts of the code and just copy pasted it.

Python

> ```
> choice = bestArm(av)
> counts[choice] += 1
> k = counts[choice]
> rwd =  reward(arms[choice])
> old_avg = av[choice]
> new_avg = old_avg + (1/k)*(rwd - old_avg) #update running avg
> av[choice] = new_avg
> ```

R

```
choice=bestArm(av)
counts[choice]=counts[choice]+1
k = counts[choice]
#reward for n arms
rwd =  reward(arms[choice])    
old_avg = av[choice]
new_avg = old_avg + (1/k)*(rwd - old_avg) #update running avg
av[choice] = new_avg
```

It runs and doesn't show any errors even after using most of the original Python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were quite a few things wrong with your implementation:

- In both the `if` and `else` parts, `choice` ended up being a numeric (a non-integer, e.g. 0.6532) when it should be an integer. The problem was that a) you where using `max` instead of `which.max` inside `bestArm` and b) randomly picking a value from `arms` instead of its index.
- Inside the `else` part, you were using `k` and `rwd` without setting them.
- your computation of the running mean was not using weights as the python implementation does
- This won't have a significant impact, but I think the python implementation had an issue: the observed mean rewards `av` should be initialized to zero, not one.

Here are other improvements I would suggest:

- The `if`/`else` should be limited to the picking of the `choice` index. Everything else should be moved after the `if`/`else` as to not repeat code. This was a problem from the original python implementation you pointed to.
- Instead of writing a script, you should write a function. It is a good way to isolate the inputs and outputs of your program, it gives you an easy way to test with different input parameters, to share your code, etc.
- use spaces to make your code easier on the eyes. Spaces also avoid ambiguous situations for people who are not experts in R's syntax rules; for example, when someone sees a<-b, is it assigning b to a, or is it asking if a is less than -b? Maybe another way to convince you is to make you notice that R's compiled code does contain spaces (run print(lapply) for example); it shows that R's authors agreed that code readability was more important than compactness.
- If you are slowly building a vector (`runMean`) and know in advance its final length, initialize it with that exact length: `runMean <- rep(NA, iter)`. Otherwise, at each iteration R will have to create a longer object and this will significantly slow down your code for any large number of iterations.

So the code could look like this:

```
n.armed.bandit.sim <- function(iter = 500, n = 10, eps = 0.1, max.reward = 100) {

  arms <- runif(n)
  av <- rep(0, n)
  counts <- rep(0L, n)

  reward  <- function(prob) sum(runif(max.reward) < prob)
  bestArm <- which.max

  runMean <- rep(NA, iter)
  for (i in seq_len(iter)) {
    choice <- if(runif(1) > eps) bestArm(av) else sample(n, 1) 
    counts[choice] <- counts[choice] + 1L
    k <- counts[choice]
    rwd <- reward(arms[choice])    
    old_avg <- av[choice]
    new_avg <- old_avg + (1 / k) * (rwd - old_avg)
    av[choice] <- new_avg
    runMean[i] <- weighted.mean(av, counts / sum(counts))
  }
  plot(runMean)
}
```